# JQuery select label of selected checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

When I click a button I want to get the value from each of the checked check boxes. I really just want to populate an array with all the check boxes that are checked.

I started a simplified example here: http://jsfiddle.net/kralco626/JvAdg/1/

The actual code is more like this:

```
var dataList = new Array(10);
dataList[0] = "Delete";
dataList[1] = LD_LicenseNumber.val();
dataList[2] = $("#LDOperatingCompanies input:checked").val();
```

And aspx code:

```
<div id="LDOperatingCompanies">
                        <input type="checkbox" value="o1"  id="o1" name="LDOperatingCompanies" /><label for="o1">o1</label>
                        <input value="o2" type="checkbox" id="o2" name="LDOperatingCompanies" /><label for="o2">o2</label>
                        <input value="o3" value="o1" type="checkbox" id="o3" name="LDOperatingCompanies" /><label for="o3">o3</label>
                    </div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does getting the value have to do with selecting the `<label>`?

Comment: Having looked at the code … your checkboxes don't have values. You need  `value` attribute for that. Don't confuse labels and values.

Comment: Re edit: Providing server side code for client side problems is rarely helpful, but that is just plain HTML anyway.

Comment: I'm a little confused because I don't have any server side code. But i'll try adding a value attribute. Didnt know I could do that.

Comment: Ok. I added in the value and it works for when I have one selected. However when I have multiple selected it still only returns the value of the first one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here is an update to your fiddle that puts all checked boxes into an array [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/JvAdg/3/)

HTML

```
<div id="LDOperatingCompanies">
    <input type="checkbox" id="o1" name="LDOperatingCompanies" /><label for="o1">o1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="o2" name="LDOperatingCompanies" /><label for="o2">o2</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="o3" name="LDOperatingCompanies" /><label for="o3">o3</label>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="alert checked boxes" />
```

JavaScript

```
var checks = [];
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
    $(':checked').each(function(index, item) {
        checks.push( item );
    });
    if(checks.length == 0) alert('nothing checked');
    else alert(checks);
});
```

Comment: how do I get the values from item? like item.val() ? It says this object does not support this method.

Comment: here is an update that gets the `id` and `value` of each selected checkbox http://jsfiddle.net/JvAdg/4/